# Facetted Barchart with percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have a data set called charities with two treatments (csr), two genders (gender) and performance of the subject (pointspr). I would like to make a histogram with percentage on the y-axis and performance on the x-axis with a facet wrap by treatment and gender. I've provided a minimal example of data.

This code produces histograms by treatment and gender but the percentages are not right. I've seen elsewhere using ..group.. for one two-dimensional variable, but I have two of them: csr and gender.

The graph for csr=0 and gender=1 should have 66.7% for pointspr=10 but the graph produced with this code has the percentage at around 15%. Thanks for any help.

```
library(ggplot)
charities <- csr=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
gender=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2), 
pointspr=c(10,5,10,15,12,12,2,2,5,1,1,4) 
 ggplot(charities, aes(x = factor(pointspr))) +  
  geom_bar(binwidth=1, aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), fill = 'lightblue') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
  facet_wrap(csr ~ gender) +
  labs(x = 'Number of correct answers under piece rate incentive', y = 'Percentage') +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing the percentage on the fly inside the `ggplot` code it is in general easier to pass an aggregated dataset to ggplot.

**EDIT** To label your numeric variable one option would be to convert them to labelled factors.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

charities <- data.frame(
  csr = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  gender = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  pointspr = c(10, 5, 10, 15, 12, 12, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 4)
)

charities <- charities %>%
  mutate(csr = factor(csr, levels = 0:1, labels = c("NSI", "SI")),
         gender = factor(gender, levels = 1:2, labels = c("Men", "Women"))) %>%
  count(csr, gender, pointspr = factor(pointspr)) %>%
  group_by(csr, gender) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(charities, aes(pointspr, pct)) +
  geom_col(fill = "lightblue") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  facet_wrap(csr ~ gender) +
  labs(x = "Number of correct answers under piece rate incentive", y = "Percentage") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

As mentioned by @RohanShinde, instead of recoding to a labelled factor a second option would be to set the labels via the `labeller` argument inside `facet_wrap` like so:

```r
facet_wrap(csr ~ gender, 
           labeller = labeller(csr = c("0" = "NSI", "1" = "SI"),
                               gender = c("1" = "Men", "2" = "Women")))
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, Stefan!!! I really appreciate your quick and helpful reply. :)

Comment: Any idea how to change the legend names from numbers to text? So 0="NSI" and 1="SI" for csr and 1="Men" and 2=Women for gender?

Comment: @Mary Rigdon You can try to use the `labeller()` argument inside `facet_wrap()`

Comment: @MaryRigdon I just made an edit to show you two options to label your factors.

Comment: Stefan, MUCH, MUCH appreciated!!!! Thank you for all of your help. I can now finish the paper I am writing. :)